# What are the precise requirements of the "Model of a Modern Major-General" achievement in Civilisation 5?

Tags: civilization-5, achievements

> ### Model of a Modern Major-General
>
> Train all Units, across any number of playthrough.

Is it known what the precise requirements are for this achievement?

- Do you actually need to *train* all units, or is it sufficient to being gifted them by City States, or via promotion via Ancient Ruins? *(like the Helicopter Gunship I acquired in a recent game :p)*
- I would assume that paying for promotion of a unit counts as "training it" - Or do they need to be built new?
- Do you need to cover all country-specific unique units, or is the equivalent default unit sufficient?  Eg, do you need to train a Janissary, a Musketeer and a Minutemen, or is just training Musketman sufficient?

<strike>I notice that [0% of users on Steam have this achievement](http://steamcommunity.com/stats/CivV/achievements), so it's possible that it's bugged.</strike> Update: 0.1% now have the achievement, so it's apparently achievable.

Comment: Helicopter gunship in ancient ruins? That's nothing against the **Barbarian Paratrooper** that plopped out of nowhere near a camp I was cleaning up… ;)

Comment: In a late game they are not barbarians anymore, they are the Indigenous peoples ;)

Comment: Among other things, you need information vegetable, animal, and mineral, to know the kings of England, and quote the fights historical, from Marathon to Waterloo, in order categorical.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to build all the basic units, plus all the civilization Unique Units from the original release nations (no DLC). I'm sure the UUs are required as I popped mine on a Naresuan's Elephant.

It was a surprise to me, but the achievement logging has apparently been re-enabled at some point so you can check on your progress. Here's how (Hat tip to this [CivFanatics forum post](http://forums.civfanatics.com/showpost.php?p=10769352&postcount=564)):

1. Navigate to My Documents/My Games/Sid Meier's Civilization 5 (my path for Win 7)
2. Open config.ini and change the LoggingEnabled line from 0 to 1
3. Run the game and it will create a text file called "achievements_debug.log" in your Logs directory under that Civ 5 folder

Interesting note, the Spaceship parts are also tracked in this log, but I'm not sure if they're required or not for the achievement.

Answer (score 7):

Building means constructing at a city or purchasing at a city, gifts and upgrades don't count.  There was once a bug preventing Lancer from being recognized so people were not getting the achievement, but that has been fixed.

Comment: One of the recent patches has disabled the feature mentioned in the  referenced forum post.

Comment: @Mufasa You're correct, I've updated my answer.